# Pandas adjust last row of dataframe group

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a list of daily level data that I have aggregated to quarterly level for each unique company/group grouping.  I then calculate the year over year growth.

However, for the current quarter, I want to adjust the year-over-year calculation to only account for the quarter-to-date period.  For example, assuming the data is current as of 11/4/2016 and the quarter started 10/1/2016 and ends 12/31/2016, I want to calculate the growth in transactions between 10/1/2016-11/4/2016 and 10/1/2015-11/4/2015.

Assuming the data is current as of 11/4/2016, how can I calculate the year over year growth for the most recent quarter that I only have partial data for?

daily data:
df =

```
Company Group Period  Date        Value 
A       X     2014Q1  02/21/2015  3     
A       X     2014Q1  03/04/2015  4
A       X     2014Q1  03/16/2015  2   
A       X     2014Q2  04/21/2015  1    
A       X     2014Q2  05/04/2015  2
A       X     2014Q2  05/16/2015  3  
A       X     2014Q3  08/03/2015  1
A       X     2014Q3  08/14/2015  2 
A       X     2014Q4  10/16/2015  4  
A       X     2014Q4  11/03/2015  2
A       X     2014Q4  12/14/2015  3     
A       X     2015Q1  02/21/2015  2     
A       X     2015Q1  03/04/2015  2
A       X     2015Q1  03/16/2015  1   
A       X     2015Q2  04/21/2015  3     
A       X     2015Q2  05/04/2015  2
A       X     2015Q2  05/16/2015  3  
A       X     2015Q3  08/03/2015  4
A       X     2015Q3  08/14/2015  2 
A       X     2015Q4  10/16/2015  1  
A       X     2015Q4  11/03/2015  1
A       X     2015Q4  12/14/2015  2 
A       X     2016Q1  02/21/2016  3     
A       X     2016Q1  03/04/2016  2
A       X     2016Q1  03/16/2016  2   
A       X     2016Q2  04/21/2016  3     
A       X     2016Q2  05/04/2016  1
A       X     2016Q2  05/16/2016  2  
A       X     2016Q3  08/03/2016  5
A       X     2016Q3  08/14/2016  4 
A       X     2016Q4  10/16/2016  3
A       XX    2015Q1  02/21/2015  2     
A       XX    2015Q1  03/04/2015  1
A       XX    2015Q1  03/16/2015  1   
A       XX    2015Q2  04/21/2015  3     
A       XX    2015Q2  05/04/2015  2
A       XX    2015Q2  05/16/2015  1  
A       XX    2015Q3  08/03/2015  4
A       XX    2015Q3  08/14/2015  2 
A       XX    2015Q4  10/16/2015  5  
A       XX    2015Q4  11/03/2015  1
A       XX    2015Q4  12/14/2015  2 
A       XX    2016Q1  02/21/2016  5     
A       XX    2016Q1  03/04/2016  2
A       XX    2016Q1  03/16/2016  2   
A       XX    2016Q2  04/21/2016  1     
A       XX    2016Q2  05/04/2016  1
A       XX    2016Q2  05/16/2016  2  
A       XX    2016Q3  08/03/2016  2
A       XX    2016Q3  08/14/2016  3 
A       XX    2016Q4  10/13/2016  1
A       XX    2016Q4  10/18/2016  1
```

quarterly data: df2=

```
Company Group Period  EndDate      Value Pct_Growth_YoY
A       X     2014Q1  3/31/2015    9     NaN
A       X     2014Q2  6/30/2015    6     NaN
A       X     2014Q3  9/30/2015    3     NaN
A       X     2014Q4  12/31/2015   9     NaN
A       X     2015Q1  3/31/2015    5     -0.44
A       X     2015Q2  6/30/2015    8     0.33
A       X     2015Q3  9/30/2015    6     1.0
A       X     2015Q4  12/31/2015   4     -0.55
A       X     2016Q1  3/31/2016    7     0.40
A       X     2016Q2  6/30/2016    6     -0.25
A       X     2016Q3  9/30/2016    9     0.50
A       X     2016Q4  12/31/2016   3     -0.25
A       XX    2015Q1  3/31/2015    4     NaN
A       XX    2015Q2  6/30/2015    6     NaN
A       XX    2015Q3  9/30/2015    6     NaN
A       XX    2015Q4  12/31/2015   8     NaN
A       XX    2016Q1  3/31/2016    9     1.25
A       XX    2016Q2  6/30/2016    4     -0.33
A       XX    2016Q3  9/30/2016    5     -0.16
A       XX    2016Q4  12/31/2016   2     -0.75
```

I want to calculate the quarter-to-date year over year growth for each unique company/group combination, instead of comparing the partial 2016Q4 to the full 2015Q4.

The result I would like is:

result=

```
Company Group Period  EndDate      Value Pct_Growth_YoY
A       X     2014Q1  3/31/2015    9     NaN
A       X     2014Q2  6/30/2015    6     NaN
A       X     2014Q3  9/30/2015    3     NaN
A       X     2014Q4  12/31/2015   9     NaN
A       X     2015Q1  3/31/2015    5     -0.44
A       X     2015Q2  6/30/2015    8     0.33
A       X     2015Q3  9/30/2015    6     1.0
A       X     2015Q4  12/31/2015   4     -0.55
A       X     2016Q1  3/31/2016    7     0.40
A       X     2016Q2  6/30/2016    6     -0.25
A       X     2016Q3  9/30/2016    9     0.50
A       X     2016Q4  12/31/2016   3     0.50
A       XX    2015Q1  3/31/2015    4     NaN
A       XX    2015Q2  6/30/2015    6     NaN
A       XX    2015Q3  9/30/2015    6     NaN
A       XX    2015Q4  12/31/2015   8     NaN
A       XX    2016Q1  3/31/2016    9     1.25
A       XX    2016Q2  6/30/2016    4     -0.33
A       XX    2016Q3  9/30/2016    5     -0.16
A       XX    2016Q4  12/31/2016   2     -0.66
```

Comment: How are you getting quarter data? Where is your code to do so?

Comment: @Parfait I have a dataframe with the quarter data (period, and QuarterEndDate). I then merge this with the daily data to add a period column, and group on the company, group, and period column.

Comment: But then why is the last row the only missing?

Comment: I've edited the question to be more clear.  It's not missing, but the year over year growth rate is incorrect.  The data is through 11/4, so when it's aggregated for the 2016Q4 quarter it only includes data from 10/1/2016-11/4/2016.  However, 2015Q4 has data for the full quarter (10/1/2015-12/31/2015), so when I calculate the growth, it compares a partial quarter to the full quarter.  Instead, I want to calculate the data for the same period: 10/1/2016-11/4/2016 compared to 10/1/2015-11/4/2015.

Comment: Can you post your `groupby` pandas code?

Comment: `df2 = df1.groupby(['Company','Group','Period']).sum().reset_index()` and `df2['Pct_Growth_YoY']= df2.sort_values('Period').groupby(['Company','Group']).pct_change(4)`

Answer (score 0):

Consider updating select rows after running your `groupby` aggregation. The select rows would be the max *Period* in each *Company* and *Group* grouping. Calculation filters out dates that occurred after today's point in time a year ago.

First, however, convert your `Date` to a `datetime` type. Below will keep rows in following range: `1/1/2015 - 11/5/2015, 1/1/2016 - today`.

```
import datetime as dt 
...

df1['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['Date'], format="%m/%d/%Y")   

# ORIGINAL GROUP BY (NO CHANGE)
df2 = df.groupby(['Company','Group','Period']).sum().reset_index()
df2['Pct_Growth_YoY'] = df2.sort_values('Period').groupby(['Company','Group'])\
                           .pct_change(4)

# LOCATE MAX QUARTER GROUP INDICES    
maxgrps = df2.groupby(['Company','Group'])['Period']\
             .apply(lambda row: row[row==row.max()].index.values[0])\
             .reset_index()['Period'].values.tolist()

# UPDATE ONLY MAX QUARTER GROUP ROWS
df2.ix[maxgrps, 'Pct_Growth_YoY'] = \
                     df[(df['Date'] <= (dt.datetime.today() - dt.timedelta(days=365.25))) |
                        (df['Date'] >= dt.datetime(dt.datetime.today().year, 1, 1))]\
                        .groupby(['Company','Group','Period']).sum().reset_index()\
                        .groupby(['Company','Group']).pct_change(4)['Value']\
                                                     .iloc[maxgrps].values
```

Comment: This produces an incorrect `Value` for 2015Q4.  Also if I had more than just two years, it would produce incorrect `Value` and `Pct_Growth_YoY`for every Q4.

Comment: For the data posted here, I get -0.66667 for 2016Q4, running your exact groupby. All December values are removed. So the *2* for 12/2015 would be dropped.

Comment: When I group after your code, the `df2.Value` for Group X in 2015Q4 is 2 and it should be 4. The `Value` column should remain the same.

Comment: I've updated the question to include data from 2014 to show the 2015Q4 `Pct_`Growth_YoY` would be incorrect using this method..

Comment: Did you also need to condition Q4 2014 to up to November values? If so, you need to use the second method in my answer (not first) that generalizes for all years in dataset.

Comment: No do not need to condition the Q4 2014 values.  But when you condition the Q4 2015 values like you have, it will mess up the Q4 2015 Value aggregation, as well as the Q4 2015 Pct_Growth_YoY.  Simply put, I do not get the same `result` using your code as in the example.

Comment: Your Value for Q42015 shows **4** for Company A / Group X and **8** for XX, showing you are counting the 12/14/15 value at **2** for both groups. Aren't December values supposed to be filtered out?

Comment: Only the Pct_Growth_YoY should be filtered out.  The result should look the exact same as the the `result` dataframe

Comment: See edit that updates select rows for the conditional YoY calculation.